# Affine semigroup generating a lattice

Tags: reference-request, convex-geometry, semigroups, monoid

Everything is assumed to be finite-dimensional. Let $S$ be a finitely generated affine semigroup (i.e. a subsemigroup of a lattice $N$). Assume that $S$ generates $N$ as a group. Is it true that it contains all but a finite number of points in $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} S\cap N?$

I believe the result should be known, however, I am not a specialist in convex geometry so book reference will be much appreciated.

EDIT: [the question was cross-posted on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416709/affine-semigroup-generating-a-lattice)